# Cycle class map and generalisation of Kummer theory

Tags: algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology

Suppose $X$ is a variety defined over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic zero, and $Z$ is a closed subvariety of codimension $c$, 
then there is a long exact sequence of etale cohomology groups,
\begin{equation}
\cdots \rightarrow H^r_{Z}(X,\Lambda) \rightarrow H^r(X,\Lambda) \rightarrow H^r(U,\Lambda) \rightarrow H^{r+1}_Z(X,\Lambda) \rightarrow \cdots
\end{equation}
where $U:=X-Z$ and $\Lambda:=\mathbb{Z}/\ell \mathbb{Z}$. What's more, the group $H^r_Z(X,\Lambda)$ vanishes when $r <2c$, so we have 
\begin{equation}
0 \rightarrow H^{2c-1}(X, \Lambda)(c) \rightarrow H^{2c-1}(U,\Lambda)(c) \rightarrow H^{2c}_Z(X,\Lambda)(c) \xrightarrow{f} H^{2c}(X,\Lambda)(c)\rightarrow \cdots
\end{equation}
From the paper [Beilinson's Conjectures](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/BSDseminar/refs/BeilinsonintroII.pdf), there is a cycle class map
\begin{equation}
cl(Z):\Lambda(0) \rightarrow H^{2c}_Z(X,\Lambda)(c)
\end{equation}
such that the composition with $f$
\begin{equation}
f \circ cl(Z):\Lambda(0) \rightarrow H^{2c}(X,\Lambda)(c)
\end{equation}
is the usual cycle class map.

**Question 1**: could anyone explain how to define the cycle class map $cl(Z)$, and show its composition with $f$ is the usual cycle class map?

When both $X$ and $Z$ are smooth, then $cl(Z)$ is just the Gysin isomorphism.

**Question 2**: Do the above constructions work when $Z$ is only a closed subscheme, e.g. $Z$ is not reduced?

Comment: The construction of the cycle map can be found in Milne (p138,139) : http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/LEC.pdf. This is a combination of the purity isomorphism $H^{2c}_Z(X,\Lambda)(c)=H^0(Z,\Lambda)(0)=\Lambda(0)$ when $Z$ is regular, and the semi purity theorem : $H^r_Z(X,\Lambda)=0$ for $r<2c$. Using these result, you can simply remove the singular locus $Y$ of $Z$ : $\Lambda(0)=H^{2c}_{Z\setminus \Lambda}(X\setminus Y,\Lambda) =H^{2c}_Z(X)$.

Comment: For question 2, I don't think this is the good question. We want to define $cl(Z)$ for a cycle (hence by linearity on the prime cycles). By the way, étale cohomology with coefficients in $\Lambda$ does not see non reduced things...

Comment: @Roland Thank you.

Comment: @Roland Sorry for bothering you with another naive question. Suppose $Z$ is a prime cycle, from the paper on Beilinson's conjectures, it seems that $H_{-Z}^*(X)$ could also be defined and there is also a long exact sequence, how to define $H_{-Z}^*(X)$, and more generally how to define $H_{C}^*(X)$ for an arbitrary cycle?

Comment: Can you point me where in the text it is defined. I have not read it and can't find it...

Comment: @Roland First formula in section 4.2, page 13, and it is the motivic version, i.e. the motivic version of Abel-Jacobi map.

Comment: @Roland I just realise that could it mean that for an arbitrary cycle $C=C^+-C^-$ (both $C^+$ and $C^-$ consist of prime cycles with positive coefficients), $H_C^*(X)$ actually mean $H^*_{C^++C^-}(X)$, and the cycle class map sends $C$ to $H^*_{C^++C^-}(X)$?

Comment: Here I read $Y\subset X$ a closed subvariety. Not a cycle, and variety implies reduced. So this is just the usual $H_Y(X)$.